# Craft 3 improvements to relationship querying?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, performance, craft3

I've been using Craft for a couple of years now and I do love it, however I consistently run into massive performance issues with it. I heavily rely on caching and eager loading - however this doesn't help when building filters that **query against relationships (i.e. 'categories' and 'entries' fields)** as the number of combinations of returned content is too high to think about caching.

**Craft 3** has been made **significantly faster** than Craft 2 according to [the website](https://craftcms.com/3), however that's ideal conditions presumably loading entries with no fields on them - because even with Craft 2 I've never got close to the numbers quoted in real world applications.

**Have any improvements been made to the performance and overhead of searching related fields and categories?**

Some people have suggested using [Algolia](http://algolia.com), but I've built a solution that's worked around the issue. I'd just rather not have to go to such extremes.

Thanks! (and thanks in advance for your time - presumably Brad :P).

---

An example of the type of scenario I'm referencing is below:

```
# Get element criterea for searching projects
$projectCriterea = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$projectCriterea->section = 'projects';
$projectCriterea->order = $orderBy;
$projectCriterea->limit = $limit;
$projectCriterea->offset = $offset;

... etc ...

# Project categories i.e. bridges
$relatedProjectTypes = [
    'targetElement' => $projectCategories,
    'field' => 'portfolioCategories',
];            

# Location (New Zealand, Australia etc).
$relatedToLocations = [
    'targetElement' => $locationCategories,
    'field' => 'portfolioLocationCategories',
];  

... etc ...

$projectCriterea->relatedTo = ['and', $relatedToLocations, $relatedProjectTypes];
```